# JAR Caching is not happening

Tags: java, caching, jar, applet

I have two jars

1. Application jar -  with manifest files (contains class files needed for hitting a server)
2. Image jar - without manifest files (contains some image files.. Thats it)

The problem is image jar is not getting cached. I am using JAVA7. My doubt is whether the jars with manifest files will be considered only for cahcing?

I can see the below in the source file.

```
PARAM NAME = "cache_archive"    VALUE="application.jar,images.jar"
PARAM NAME = "cache_version"    VALUE="4.0.13.2,1.0.0.0"
```

Comment: *"The problem is image jar is not getting cached."*  What information is it that leads you to believe that?

Comment: I can verify it in the java control panel.

Comment: Where specifically?  Which tab, what button, copy/paste the exact information you are seeing.  And when in doubt, give more information rather than less.  I'm not in the mood for '20 questions'.

Comment: In the java cache viewer...

You can go there by clicking the view button in the temporary internet files under general tab